# Git: iOS Create an experimental iPad branch

Tags: iphone, ios, git, github

I have built an iOS app which I would now like to test converting to an iPad version.  Since it will be experimental, I assume that I need to make a new "iPad" branch to work on this?

Is this the best way to work on something that is experimental, and where I don't want these changes in my master unless I merge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply just branch it as if it was any other branch.

```
git branch iPadDev
```

Then checkout that branch:

```
git checkout iPadDev
```

Work as if it was normal.

Once satisfied, merge it back into master if you desire.

```
git merge iPadDev
```

Comment: Can I then push small bug fixes from my master back into the new iPadDev branch?

Comment: Yes. I think you can rebase your iPadDev branch with your master, which should give you the small fixes from master into your new branch. Though rebasing is kinda dangerous if someone else pulled your iPadDev branch.

Comment: Even easier, try `git checkout -b iPadDev`.

Comment: Yep! does the checkout and creation for you!

Comment: @Jonathan - You are saying git checkout -b iPadDev will push my small changes from the master into my experimental branch?

Comment: No, it is just equivalent to `git branch iPadDev; git checkout iPadDev`.